# Prusa i3 MK2 thermistor connector reference

Tags: prusa-i3

I think my heat bed thermistor is broken (infinite resistance measured) on my Prusa MK2, so I bought a new one, and I'd like to know which connector I shall use. Where can I find the references of this connector, please ?

[image: Picture of the connector]
Regards,

Comment: A better, in-focus, photo might be required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are JST SYP 2 pins female.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer, although you may have to wait 48 hours.

Answer (score 1):

The thermistor is just a resistor. Polarity doesn't matter. Connect it wherever the old one was connected. Typically it connects to a pair of male pins on a RAMPS board, so a 2-pin female connector with standard 2.54 mm (0.1") pin spacing is called for, unless your printer uses a different board.

For a visual reference, look at the extruder RTD connection on your printer.